# total class specialization for a template

Tags: c++, templates, special-characters, template-specialization

lets say i have a templated class

```
template <typename T>
struct Widget
{
   //generalized implementation
}
```

**but i wanted to totally specialize..
for a template that accepted a parameter?**

```
template <>
struct Widget< TemplateThatAcceptsParameter<N> >
{
       //implementation for Widget for TemplateThatAcceptsParameterN 
       //which takes parameter N
}
```

How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a *partial specialization* and can be coded like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Widget
{
   //generalized implementation
};

template <typename N>
struct Widget< TemplateThatAcceptsParameter<N> >
{
   //implementation for Widget for TemplateThatAcceptsParameterN 
   //which takes parameter N
};
```

It works just like a regular specialization, but has an extra template argument.

Comment: +1. Important caveat: only for `struct` and `class`, does not apply to functions (it's overloading then).

Comment: +1, works also for `union` (which are also classes like `struct` and `class`).

Answer (score 1):

```
template < typename N >
struct Widget< template_thing<N> >
{
  ...
};
```